# How to login using facebook in development environment using django social-auth?

Tags: django, facebook, django-socialauth

I'm using social-auth with my django web app.  When I go to /login/facebook in the production environment, the user is able to login using their facebook data.  However in my development environment when I access

```
http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/,
```

I get an error saying

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

I believe this is because the domain is localhost:8000.  How do I fix this so I can login using facebook in my development environment?

Comment: Define a custom domain (I use myapp.com) when creating the app in Facebook, then add it to your `/etc/hosts/` file pointing to your local host `127.0.0.1    myapp.com`. That will do the trick

Comment: I'm unfamiliar on how to add the domain to /etc/hosts/.  Is there a good link/tutorial you would recommend?

Comment: `man hosts` has all the basic information, it's not really complicated, you add a new line with the format `<IP ADDRESS> <DOMAIN>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had just seen an answer for it while reading the Heroku/Facebook documentation.

To do that, you must create a second app and link it to your localhost in order to test it locally.

You can find more info about it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#1-creating-a-development-facebook-app

Comment: I configured the facebook app settings to be Site URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/.  App Domain: (empty).  I'm not so sure about the app domain because I didn't see anything in the link about it.  Is that correct?  When I try to save App Domain: http://127.0.0.1:8000/, I get an error saying "App Domains: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ should not contain protocol information.
App Domains: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ is not a valid domain."

Comment: I just changed an app of mine to http://127.0.0.1:8000 and it works just fine (it doesn't work without the http)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I found is to modify the hosts file to trick Facebook:

1/ Edit the hosts file

- Open /etc/hosts
- And add this line at the end: 127.0.0.1 dev.mydomain.com

2/ In the Facebook dev console (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/*********)

- Select "Test apps" > "create a test app"
- In "Settings" > "Basic" >
  Add the domain (dev.mydomain.com) into "App Domains" field.

Done!

cf:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-social-auth/gB1D8ikgUwM