# How do I access the token generated using django's social auth?

Tags: python, django, facebook, token, django-socialauth

I am using django's social_auth for facebook authentication.  I am trying to access the token once a user is logged in using facebook so the app can do things like retrieve the user's friends and what is on his/her newsfeed.  However, I am having trouble getting that token.  Below is what I have.  {{instance}} displays in the template but when I add {{token}} I get an error saying 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'tokens'.  How do I get the generated token?

## view

```
def friends(request):   
    instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(provider='facebook') 
    token = instance.tokens
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/friends.html', {'token':token, 'instance':instance},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## template

```
{{instance}}
<br>
{{token}}
```

Comment: Hey, Just curious to know..How did you access(import) UserSocialAuth model. Because When I import-> from social_auth.models import UserSocialAuth. It gives me error(Unresolved refrence). Please help.

Comment: Try from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all: a `QuerySet` is a collection of whatever your searched for (in this case, `UserSocialAuth`). To get a field in that model you need to iterate over the collection:

```
tokens = [x.tokens for x in instance]
```

As an alternative, if you're sure your filter will return **exactly** one instance (not zero, not 2 or more) you can use `get` instead of `filter`:

```
instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=request.user, provider='facebook') 
token = instance.tokens
```

Note however that a single provider can return [more than one token](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tokens.html), like `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`, so you should select which one you want and/or format it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, this works! As a separate question, can you help me troubleshoot using social auth in my development environment?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576551/how-to-login-using-facebook-in-development-environment-using-django-social-auth

Comment: @sharataka I'm still learning django-social-auth, not sure if I'll be able to answer that other question. But I'll take a closer look and see if I can help somehow.

Comment: I prefer to use `user.social_auth.filter(provider='facebook')[0]` instead of `get`, since `get` can drop an multiple-objects error, and `[0]` adds a `limit 1` to the query anyway.

Comment: @omab wouldn't that hide an application logic error instead of failing fast? If your premises are wrong (the query *should* return a single object, but *doesn't*), the bug will be a lot harder to find that way. And if your models are well designed - for instance, having `unique_together = (("user", "provider"),)` - that wouldn't be a concern.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, if your code is limiting the number of Facebook connections to just one per user, then yes `.get(...)` is better, otherwise the code should iterate over the social-accounts related or just get one based on some criteria.